# Put dummy data into html mockup using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascript-framework

I am not able to articulate well on this question .. please excuse the ambiguity.

I have a set of html screens(plain html and css). I plan to show a mockup to my higherups ASAP. Is there any way in javascript that I can store  **multiple** dummy values ans show them. and also If the user makes any changes to the dummy values it should be saved atleast till restart of application.

I summary i want to simulate a database backend based application using javascript.

Edited:  emphasis added to multiple dummy values

regards

Answer (score 1):

You could store some information in JSON arrays on the page, maybe use jQuery.data() to store them in an element.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/